# `apt is not found` when trying to install software on a new Ubuntu laptop from Dell

Tags: apt, latex

I have purchased a new Ubuntu system from Dell. To install Latex, we tried the following commands:

```
sudo apt -get update
sudo apt -get install texlive -full
```

Both the commands do not work. After giving first command it asks for [sudo] password. When we give administrative password, it says  'apt is not found'.  We also tried to install 'tilda' by giving the following command.

```
sudo apt -get install tilda
```

It also says 'apt is not found'. It does not recognize Advanced Packaging Tool (APT). What is problem?

Comment: There should be no space between `apt` and `-get` - the command is `apt-get`

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, when you run `sudo` you are prompted for the password.  The password would be the password for the user logged in.  So if you are under the user `foo`, the password you would enter is the password for `foo`.  It won't show the typed characters or even placeholders though.

Secondly, there is no space between `apt` and `-get`.  The actual program is called `apt-get`.

Thirdly, there should not be ANY spaces in the package name, so `texlive -full` is wrong, it is `texlive-full`.

Therefore, the commands you should be running are:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
sudo apt-get install tilda
```

Alternatively you can try the following to actually use the `apt` tool instead of `apt-get`, however I would recommend that you use `apt-get` instead:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install texlive-full
sudo apt install tilda
```